# Remove duplicate by matching string part of text

Tags: c#

Check the code bellow. Here i am creating a method that simply should remove the duplicate from the list `foo`. If you see the list values they are product id and quantity derived by `:` so the first part of number before `:` is product and and second part of number after `:` is the product quantity. I am taking this list into `RemoveDuplicateItems()` method for processing. This method should remove all matching product id items from whole list but my current method just returns exactly same list which i am taking on input. How can i fix my method to remove those item from list which has matching first part number. (first part number means before `:`)

The final output on `doo` variable it should remove the first from from list which is `22:15` since it has matching with second one.

C#:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DoSomething()
{

    var foo = new List<string>();
    foo.Add("22:10");//this should removed by RemoveDuplicateItems() since it has `22` matching with second one
    foo.Add("22:15");
    foo.Add("25:30");
    foo.Add("26:30");

    var doo = RemoveDuplicateItems(foo);

    return Json("done");
}

public List<string> RemoveDuplicateItems(List<string> AllItems)
{
    var FinalList = new List<string>();

    var onlyProductIds = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in AllItems)
    {
        Match result = Regex.Match(item, @"^.*?(?=:)");
        onlyProductIds.Add(result.Value);
    }
    var unique_onlyProductIds = onlyProductIds.Distinct().ToList();
    foreach (var item in AllItems)
    {
        Match result = Regex.Match(item, @"^.*?(?=:)");
        var id = unique_onlyProductIds.Where(x => x.Contains(result.Value)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (id != null)
        {
            FinalList.Add(item);
        }
    }
    return FinalList;
}
```

Comment: `var unique = from value in foo let key = value.split(':')[0] group value by key into g select g.Last();`

Comment: @AluanHaddad can you implement it in example code? your idea is not clear to me so

Comment: @AluanHaddad Replace `split` with `Split` and copy to an answer and you'll get my vote

Comment: That's all you need to do. Replace `var unique` is your `var doo`. Just delete `var doo = RemoveDuplicateItems(foo);`

Comment: @vc74, good catch. `from value in foo let key = value.Split(':')[0] group value by key into g select g.Last();`

Comment: @DillGates here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lb7IIP

Comment: i tried like this and returns null: `var doo = (from value in foo let key = value.Split(':')[0] group value by key into g select g.Last());`

Comment: It doesn't check the fiddle. Besides, that cannot return `null` be definition.

Comment: @AluanHaddad your syntax works but i have a question its not linq syntax then what it is? seems like sql command?

Comment: It is LINQ syntax. That's first class in C#. Read about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
List<string> doo =
    foo
        .Select(x => x.Split(':'))
        .GroupBy(x => x[0], x => x[1])
        .Select(x => $"{x.Key}:{x.Last()}")
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, one is, as suggested by @Aluan Haddad is to use Linq. His comment uses the [query syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq) but would could use the method syntax too (I assumed you use C#8):

```
List<string> doo = foo.GroupBy(str => str[0..2])
                      .Select(entry => entry.Last())
                      .ToList();
```

Note that this works because the current implementation of `GroupBy` preserves ordering.

Comment: The query syntax was introduced in C# 3. If you want to use the method syntax, that's a matter of taste. But the `.ToList()` is pointless.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I just respected the OP's requirements

Comment: Fair enough. But you must see the same thing I do. People doing `ToList` right before they do `foreach` and that's the last thing they do with the IEnumerable<T>. People seem to think they always need it. But the use of range syntax is nice. +1

Comment: @AluanHaddad Fully with you on that one, but since the OP did not specify how he/she'd use `doo` I kept the specs as is

Answer (score 2):

you can do it using `Linq` :

```
var doo = foo.Select(x =>
{
    var split = x.Split(':');
    return new { Key = split[0], Value = split[1] };
})
.GroupBy(x => x.Key)
.OrderBy(x => x.Key)
.Select(x =>
    {
        var max = x.LastOrDefault();
        return $"{max.Key}:{max.Value}";
    }
).ToList();
```

Comment: Why use `KeyValuePair` when an anonymous type or a tuple would do? Also the OP hasn't said that the max value is required.

Comment: @Enigmativity it's a habit :), but yes, anonymous would do the job. and yes, op didn't mention the max, but from the output I assumed it.

Comment: @DillGates that's okay, I'll update it. thanks for explaining.